# Is there a direct way to know the dispatch order of errnos from manpage?

Tags: linux, system-calls, manpage

### Background

I am implementing syscall wrappers for libc. As a natural requirement, I will need to add unit tests to the wrappers. I rely heavily on https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/dir_all_alphabetic.html and https://linux.die.net/man/2/ to learn about the expected return values and `errno` of these wrappers.

### The Problem

Well, sometimes the `errno` does not work out as expected. For example,

```cpp
unsigned long page_size = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
void * page = mmap(nullptr, page_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                                  MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);
EXPECT_THAT(mlock(holder.addr, negative_size), Fails(EINVAL));
```

According to the manpage, the above syscall wrapper should have set `EINVAL` purely based POSIX's expectation, since:

> EINVAL: The result of the addition addr+len was less than addr (e.g., the addition may have resulted in an overflow).

However, if you run it in a constrained environment, say `ulimit -l 16384`. You will actually get a `ENOMEM`. This is because:

> ENOMEM: (Linux 2.6.9 and later) the caller had a nonzero RLIMIT_MEMLOCK soft resource limit, but tried to lock more memory than the limit permitted. This limit is not enforced if the process is privileged (CAP_IPC_LOCK).

If you check the code inside Linux kernel, the permissions and limits are checked before the overflow examination. (https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/mm/mlock.c#L624)

This looks a little bit unsatisfactory to me in the sense that solely based on the manpage, I actually cannot know the expect behavior of the syscall wrappers. I also notice that `man7.org` and `linux.die.net` even list these errnos in completely different order. Therefore, is there a clean way to know which errno is actually expected? Do I need to inspect the kernel code everytime?

Comment: I don't think there's a specified priority order. If there are multiple problems, it could report any one of them.

Comment: So if you're writing unit tests, you shouldn't depend on a specific one being reported, have it accept any of the possible errors.

Comment: The source you probably should check is the POSIX spec, not man pages. But I don't think it's specific about this, either.

Comment: Generally there is no way to determine the order of `errno`s based on a manpage or from the POSIX specification.

Comment: I just checked POSIX.1-2001. It uses strong words "shall fail" on those required errno while using vague words "may fail" on those whose implementation may diverge. The `EINVAL` into the above case falls in the second category. It would be better if the `manpage` distinguishes "may fail" and "shall fail".